# Error while starting AX 2012 R3 service

Tags: sql-server, windows, service, axapta

I have installed a fresh instance of AX 2012 R3 on my system. When I try to start the service on my machine i get the following error:

[image: Error 1067 the process terminated unexpectedly]

[image: The event log for the same is as shown]

Note: When I try to start the service through Local system it works. But I want to start it through the account NT Authority/Network Service. Any suggestions?

Another anomaly is that when i try to install DIXF it gives me the following error: "Verify that you have enough privileges to start the service"

Comment: You may want to edit that second image as it shows some identifying information.

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like you've narrowed the issue down yourself. Do you **need** to have it running as the network service account? Run it as your user or another user with access to SQL.

I'd say that it's a permissions issue to SQL and/or file permissions on the machine the AOS resides on.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd362055.aspx

Comment: +1 as it might solve the OP's specific situation, but should it not throw an understandable error message instead of crash?

Comment: In an ideal world, it would for sure give a clear error, but you know Microsoft. IF it actually is the issue, then I would say it's a rarer case that anyone uses network service, as it should be a domain user and Microsoft says that you can do that for Dev/Test only...but it's not really the expected setup.  So I wouldn't blame them for not having a terribly clear error.

Comment: Yeah I agreed with the answer, I wanted to document the steps to take in case of a random crash in mine.

Comment: Hi Alex, 
I will try running it as a domain account. But the data import export framework installation which is failing too, is under a different account and it says "Not enough priveleges to start the service"

Comment: I tried running it as a domain account but to no avail. It gives the same error. LocalSystem is still working fine.

Comment: This points to permissions in my mind. Since we don't have access to your system, we can only speculate, but you can use process of elimination to determine. Use a domain account that's a SQL SysAdmin, local admin on the SQL box, and local admin on the AOS box, and verify folder permissions to the AOS server directory. If it works, then you know there are some limiting/lacking permissions somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Debugging a crashing AOS server is not a simple task.

As I see from your Event Log you are running build number `6.3.164.0` which is the RTM build of 2012 R3. Many hotfixes have been released since and there is a good chance your problem goes away with just installing the latest kernel build. See [Overview of Microsoft Dynamics AX build numbers](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/axsupport/2012/03/29/overview-of-microsoft-dynamics-ax-build-numbers/) for links to more recent builds.
Running a newer kernel with an older application build is supported, but since it's a fresh instance I'd update the application too.

If you would have a go at debugging this yourself you could try to get a memory dump to analyze with windbg. Refer to this article [So your AOS crashed, is hanging, or you just want to see what it's doing](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/emeadaxsupport/archive/2011/04/10/so-your-aos-crashed-is-hanging-or-you-just-want-to-see-what-it-s-doing.aspx) .
Unfortunately my results with that approach have been mixed. Unfortunately we don't have access to all debugging symbols we need, and in this case, since it crashes immediately on startup I don't know what to expect.

Your third and last option is to open a support ticket with Microsoft and provide them with memory dumps, but their suggestion will be to update to a more recent build anyway.